# WooCommerce - Display total number of cart products in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display the total number of items a customer has in their cart on the checkout page.

I've read in the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) that I need to use `get_cart_contents_count` but when I try this it outputs 1 no matter how many items I have.

**NB:** "`get_cart_contents_count( )`
Get number of items in the cart.
Returns
integer"

The code I have is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $_cartQty = count( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count( ) );
    echo $_cartQty;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I thought I had been quite clever getting to this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a count which is making it not work - try this:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $_cartQty = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count( );
    echo $_cartQty;
}
```

If I was you I would change it to:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {        
    return WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
}
```

I would never echo from a function like this - in general combining php and HTML like that is not any good.

I would `<?= $class->my_custom_checkout_field() ?>`

Comment: Brilliant, I removed the "count" and it worked. Thank you. BTW, I'm not going to echo the number. I want to test if it's over 1 and then change the form fields. The echo was just for testing.

Comment: Good good -  try to help yourself to use a debugger like xdebugger - I learned it way to late.

Comment: BTW. In your answer you say "cout". I tried to edit it to "count" but edits have to be 6 characters or more.

Comment: It is edited now - if you like the answer you could upvote and accept it as the answe